# Is there any possibility to get top hot keys in Oracle Coherence?

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

Problem that hides behind of my question is to load to cache after system failed the most hot entities that was invoked during the last session.

So, is there any possibility in Oracle Coherence to get top of the hot entities(the most often caused by keys)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it's **not** super easy, and takes some understanding of backing maps and distributed processing in Coherence. Basically, you'll need to ask each entry (see ConfigurableCacheMap.Entry interface) for its getTouchCount() property. This isn't easy because it's on the backing map, and you'd have to do that on each server that manages data. I'd suggest doing a "top 10" (or however many) per partition, so that collecting this info is a partition-by-partition approach.